# Rewrite URL's Glype (nginx)

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, nginx

I've a Glype proxy and I want to rewrite the URL's. All URLs on the page are automatically converted to: http://proxy.com/browse.php?u=[URL HERE]. Example: If I go to /browse on The Pirate Bay on my proxy I want to convert the URL from this:

```
proxy.com/tpb/browse.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fthepiratebay.se%2Fbrowse&b=0
```

To this:

```
proxy.com/tpb/browse
```

As you can see, the whole part:

```
browse.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fthepiratebay.se%2F
```

Is gone (and the `&b=0` what is behind the URL). And it has the same domain structure as The Pirate Bay .

I've tried something like this:

```
        location /tpb/ {
        rewrite ^/browse.php?u=(.*)$ /$1? last;
        break;
            }
```

But it is not working. Somebody has an answer? An other function is also welcome. (Such as  `fastcgi_split_path_info` or something else what is compatible with nginx)

(If you want see a example go to [tpb.piratenpartij.nl](http://tpb.piratenpartij.nl) but I'm not sure if they are using Glype)

Comment: I don't know why you want this, but if it is because you want to hide the site's url (so that users their history is (sort of) anonymous), Glype offers a functionality for this, it is called url-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `proxy.com/tpb/browse.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fthepiratebay.se%2Fbrowse&b=0` would match `location /tpb/browse.php`, so you can write

```
location /tpb/browse.php {
    rewrite ^/tpb/browse\.php.* $host/tpb/browse redirect;
}
```

Hope it does what you wanted, it does not care about ?u=, do you really need it?

Let me know if it works, I have nowhere to try it right now.

Comment: Unfortunately is it not working. I've tried with `if (!-e $request_filename)` and closed with `break;` but also that is not working. If you have an other solution, let me know. Thanks in advance.